# Using twitteR's getRetweeters method

Tags: r

I can't figure out how to use this method.  Having authenticated with `{twitteR}`, the following code illustrates:

```
status <- showStatus('572173453467365376')
status$getRetweeters()
Error in check_id(id) : object 'self' not found
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `?status` - an object of class status has no method getRetweeters. It has a method `status$toDataFrame()` and fields like `status$retweetCount`. However, you can use `retweeters(status$getId())` to get what you probably want.

Comment: That's confusing. `str(status)` returns a list of methods: `and 51 methods, of which 39 are possibly relevant: getCreated, ... getRetweeters`.  

And `status$getRetweeters` in console returns:

`Class method definition for method getRetweeters()
function (n = 20, ...) 
{
    return(retweeters(self$getId(), n, ...))
}
<environment: 0x000000002c5a3ab8>`

Comment: Huh, you are right. The method is there, but it seems as if it isn't implemented correctly... I just looked at the documentation...

Comment: Probably is the right process but needs to be called as you describe for environmental reasons.

Comment: Maybe. Would be something for the mailing list http://lists.hexdump.org/pipermail/twitter-users-hexdump.org/