# getRetweeters() returns one id whereas getRetweetCount() returns 2 -- in twitteR package

Tags: r, twitter

I use twitteR package and I am trying to retrieve account ids of retweeters..
The retweeterCount and the list of retweeters does not appear to be always consistent.

For example, I retrieved a status (tweet) using

```r
st<-showStatus("1058168768009043969")
retweeters(st$getId()) # returns "260857015" 
st$getRetweetCount() # however returns 2
st$getRetweeters() # returns a known error
```

## [Using twitteR's getRetweeters method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810736/using-twitters-getretweeters-method)

twitter site shows 2 retweets as shown here
https://twitter.com/ConsueloMack/status/1058168768009043969

In order to run one needs a valid key and setup the oauth as follows

```r
require('twitteR')
twapi<-read.csv("./coach_keys.json",sep=":",stringsAsFactors=F,header=F)

# in Linux you can obtain oauth as follows 
setup_twitter_oauth(twapi[twapi$V1=="API_KEY",c("V2")],
twapi[twapi$V1=="API_SECRET_KEY",c("V2")],
twapi[twapi$V1=="ACCESS_TOKEN",c("V2")],
twapi[twapi$V1=="ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET",c("V2")])

# then the above snippet can be run
```

I expected the retweeters method to return as many as indicated by
the getRetweetCount().

However, it does not. I am seeking some pointers especially if I am doing something wrong. Is it common occurrence? Can someone show for the ID I have how to retrieve count and the list consistent with each other?
Thank you very much.